# How to send params when routing without using the query in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I am new in Next.js, and I would like to send parameters when the page switching from one page to another one. Then I can only find the way to send params through the query of URL.
For avoiding this, I can use the Context or Redux. But, is there a certain way to solve this problem without using these? In react-router, this is not a problem
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code snippet.

<Button onClick={() =>Router.push({pathname: "/results",
query: { formDisplay: false }})}>

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond, here is my code snippet.

Comment: <Button
      className={classes.navLink}
      onClick={() =>
             Router.push({
             pathname: "/results",
             query: { formDisplay: false },
         })
      }
>

Comment: You can check query:{}....

Comment: Please use the edit function and edit your post to add these examples.

Comment: The props you are talking about in react-router works the same as passing props in custom _app.js (in next.js world). Read more about it here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app
From your example I am not sure that it is the case

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I customize this _app.js file for supporting the router props like the react router?